# Remove &nbsp; from shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I'm not sure why I can't get this to work. I'm trying to remove the `&nbsp;` that is added inside this shortcode...

```
[box] Text [/box]
```

Which results in this HTML output:

```
<div class="box">&nbsp; Text &nbsp;</div>
```

I want to remove those spaces. I tried to usr str_replace, but it's not removing the &nbsp :

```
function infoButton($atts, $content = null) {
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(

    'class' => '',

    ), $atts ));

    $str = '<div class="box ' . $class . '">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
    $new_str = str_replace('&nbsp;','',$str);

    return $new_str; 

    }
    add_shortcode('box', 'infoButton');
```

Comment: Could you use [PHP `trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)?

Comment: I just tried `return trim($str,"&nbsp;")` but no change.

Comment: You'd use  `$str = '<div class="box ' . $class . '">' . do_shortcode( trim( $content ) ) . '</div>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to the `do_shortcode` running through `wpautop`, see here for details on disabling that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940854/disable-automatic-formatting-inside-wordpress-shortcodes

But as `frogg3862` said, what you need to do instead of that is to just [trim out the beginning and ending whitespace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) from `$content` to prevent the [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) from being automatically added.

```
function infoButton($atts, $content = null) {
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(

    'class' => '',

    ), $atts ));

    $str = '<div class="box ' . $class . '">' . do_shortcode( trim( $content ) ) . '</div>';

    return $str; 

}
add_shortcode('box', 'infoButton');
```